# MVVM Command in Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, datatemplate

I have in my XAML a Datatemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SheetToTemplate">
            <TextBox Name="_txtToSheet"
                    Text="{Binding Path=SHEET_TO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource DigitOnlyTextBoxStyle}" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.FilterTextChangedCommand }" >
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
```

This is my viewmodel with essential part:

```
RelayCommand _filterTextChangedCommand;
public ICommand FilterTextChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_filterTextChangedCommand == null)
        {
            _filterTextChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => TextChange(param),
                param => true);
        }

        return _filterTextChangedCommand;
    }
}

private object TextChange(object param)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This is the error I get in output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.FilterTextChangedCommand;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'InvokeCommandAction'
>   (HashCode=46858895); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I don't understand why the event isn't fired.
Any suggestion?

ps. Note that the property of the textbox is correctly bound.

**EDIT**

here the full control

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedOperations}"
                    Margin="5,10,5,5" 
                    Name="WorkOrders" 
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    FontSize="13"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    BorderBrush="AliceBlue">

    <!--Style of items-->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <!--Properties-->
            <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <!--Trigger-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Operation" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DetailIdenTemplate}"  Width="300"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="From" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SheetFromTemplate}"  Width="50"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="To" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SheetToTemplate}" Width="50" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And here the ViewModel class definition:

```
public class OperativeSheetSelectionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     //
}
```

Comment: Do you see anything in Output when using Visual Studio 2015 (with enabled binding debugging)?

Comment: Sure. I forgot it... I'm editing my post

Comment: Where is your `DataTemplate` defined? In the resources of the `UserControl`?

Comment: @Tomtom yes in Window.Resources tag

Comment: I tried to add the datatemplate directly where I need it but the result is the same.

Comment: Why do you need the `RelativeSource`? Show us the whole markup including the `UserControl` you trying to reference.

Comment: @dymanoid I edited my post.

Comment: I don't see any `UserControl` though.

Comment: @dymanoid ok. So What should I set instead of UserControl?

Comment: Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599(v=vs.100).aspx) carefully. You need to specify the type of ancestor object you want to find.

Comment: @dymanoid so I need to set the type of my control? In this case I have a Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.
The error was on the AncestorType. I need a Window, not an UserControl. (...)